# How to get Transport Stream encoded files to properly display file icon image?

Tags: ffmpeg

I don't know if I am asking this correctly but here goes.
I got a DVD box set for my birthday and trans-coded the files to store on my computer for viewing. After dumping the raw files to my computer I compressed them with the following batch command;

```
INPUT="$1"
for i in *.mp4 ; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec h264 -acodec libfaac "$i.ts"
mv "$i.ts" "$i.mp4"
sleep 3
done
```

Which resulted in a great compression and quality but when I look at the folder the files are located in the icons are just gray boxes, when the original files in the same folder had an image of the video displayed.
(Lol, I know its just cosmetic but its bugging me :)

If I use the command;

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

It displays the image icon fine but encodes as (AVC1) instead of (h264) which is not what I want.

Is there a way I can address this in my batch file command to get it to display the file icon as desired?
Thank you!

Comment: H.264 == AVC. The former is the ITU codename, and the latter the MPEG committee's.  Also, TS and MP4 are separate containers - you can't just rename the extension. Remux: `ffmpeg -i in.ts -c copy out.mp4`

Comment: Thank you for the information and comment. The command you provided produced an error, the correction for the error is the command;

ffmpeg -i in.ts -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c copy out.mp4

Comment: You're using a very old version of ffmpeg. Recent versions automatically insert bsfs as needed. I should have realized that earlier since you're using libfaac whose support was removed in Oct 2016.

Comment: Opps that hadn't occurred to me thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the information Gyan provided I was able to come up with an effective solution to the question I asked for modification of my batch file command which is as follows.

```
INPUT="$1"
for i in *.mp4 ; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec h264 -acodec libfaac "$i.ts"
ffmpeg -i "$i.ts" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -c copy "$i.mp4"
rm *.ts
sleep 3
done
```

However, given the information Gyan provided we can skip the step of encoding to a transmission stream file and then to remux to mp4 and simply compress the mp4 file in the following batch command.

```
INPUT="$1"
for i in *.mp4 ; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec h264 -acodec libfaac "$i.mp4"
sleep 3
done
```

Keeping in mind that this was done using an older version of ffmpeg.
For newer versions of ffmpeg use the following to compress your video maintaining a proper image icon of the video you are compressing;

```
INPUT="$1"
for i in *.mp4 ; do
ffmpeg -i "$i" -vcodec h264 -acodec aac "$i.mp4"
sleep 3
done
```

The only issue using the batch file command is it will add an extra file extension to the file name (filename.mp4.mp4) which I address using pyrenamer to remove the extra file extension in all files under multiple directories in a single click.

If someone knows how to address this inside the batch command please comment and I will modify this answer. I have tried variations of the 'mv' command but no luck.

Comment: You will have to work with temporary files, for example by adding a second extension that you have to remove later. You could also just write the files into another directory and `mv` them back in order to overwrite the originals.